# In a bottom-up evaluation of a syntax directed definition, inherited attributes can

Tags: compilers, syntax, code-generation

In a bottom-up evaluation of a syntax directed definition, inherited attributes can

1. always be evaluated
2. be evaluated only if the definition is L-attributed
3. be evaluated only if the definition has synthesized attributes
4. never be evaluated

---

My attempt:

> Option $(3)$ should be true, since ,
>
> Synthesized Attributes: They are computed from the values of the
>   attributes of the children nodes.
>
> Inherited Attributes: They are computed from the values of the
>   attributes of both the siblings and the parent nodes.

But, one of my friends commented that "Your explanation is correct, but option C says "has" not "is"." (In fact, I did not get this comment).

---

Somewhere it explain as below:

A Syntax Directed Definition (SDD) is called S Attributed if it has only synthesized attributes.

L-Attributed Definitions contain both synthesized and inherited attributes but do not need to build a dependency graph to evaluate them.
So, option $(2)$ is true.

> > Can you explain it in a formal way, please?

Comment: You should not simply copy and paste a 'gate" question along with comments given on some website.You should take some efforts later if you have some douts then you can post them here

Comment: @Maharaj, it seems ok to post original question.

Comment: The title you have chosen is not well suited to representing your question. Please take some time to improve it; we have collected some advice [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/a/815/). Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

Indeed option (2) is true.

Synthesized attributes contain those attributes which inherit properties from their children.

Inherited attributes are those which inherit properties from their parents or their left siblings.

L-attributed definitions contain both synthesized and inherited attributes.

So for an SDT to evaluate inherited attributes, it must follow L-attributed definition.

Answer (score -1):

3) would be the answer because synthesized attributes are evaluated using Bottom up parsing.Stack is used for this which is implemented using arrays.